# How to browse and open file from all folders in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, csv, plugins, xamarin.forms

hi all I am developing an xamarin.forms app and here I need to read data from csv and also should be able to write csv ,so in android app I am downloading the csv and I am able to read and write it ,for this I am using plugin.filepicker to browse and open the file I am able to open the file only from downloads folder and I am not able to open it if its in any other folder like file browser ,sd card etc ,here I am attaching the code for this please review it and let me know where I can change it because I am downloading the csv from mail so its in downloads folder I am able to browse and open it from downloads folder but after updating the csv and saving it the newly generated csv is stored in sd card in file browser so whenever I try to open that I am getting an exception

code :

```
private string fileName;
public string FileName

{
    get { return fileName; }
    set
    {
        fileName = value;
    }
}

private Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions.FileData file = 
default(Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions.FileData);

public async void OnBrowse(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        // var file_path =  
        this.file = await 
            CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile().ConfigureAwait(true);           
            /*CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();//*/
        if (this.file == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string extensionType = this.file.FileName.Substring(
            this.file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".",
                StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1,
                this.file.FileName.Length - 
                    this.file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 1)
                        .ToLower();

        fileName = this.file.FileName;

        if (extensionType.Equals("csv"))
        {
            csv_file.Text = (fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            await this.DisplayAlert("Name of the file:" + file.FileName, 
                "File info", "OK");
        }

        if (SettingsPage.loggingEnabled)
        {               
            LogUtilPage.Initialize(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.file.FilePath));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something went wrong", "OK");
        if (SettingsPage.loggingEnabled)
        {
            LogUtilPage.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the specific exception you are getting?

Comment: exception is : index was out of range.Must be non-negative and less than the size of collection.parameter name : index

Comment: is the exception coming from your code, or from the Plugin?  If it's in your code, which line is it?

Comment: first it used to come from plugin the above shared exception and now I implemented logging for troubleshooting so now I am getting the alert as something went wrong from code from the catch part at end                          
       catch (Exception e)
        {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something went wrong", "OK");
        if (SettingsPage.loggingEnabled)
        {
            LogUtilPage.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }

Comment: the stack trace on the exception object will help you determine which line caused it, or use the debugger in the IDE to interactively debug.  More than likely there is a bug when you assign `extensionType`